# How do I correctly output glyphicon based on my int field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I get `glyphicon` to appear based on `int` field in my razor page?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="glyphicon">
                @item.Status == 0 ? &#xe157; : &#xe067;
            </span>
        </td>
```

Image shows incorrect output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of razor when trying to mix code blocks and content when the content is not wrapped in html tags

2 options you can use are

```
<span class="glyphicon">
    @(item.Status == 0 ? @Html.Raw("&#xe157;") : @Html.Raw("&#xe067;"));
</span
```

or using razors `@:` syntax (which denotes that the line is treated as html content)

```
<span class="glyphicon">
    @if(item.Status == 0) { 
        @:&#xe157;
    } else { 
        @:&#xe067;
    }
</span
```

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this? Maybe in the controller or some where more appropriate?

Comment: If you use a view model, then you can always add a (say) `string Glyphicon` property and assign it based on the `Status` property, and then it would be just `<span class="glyphicon">@Html.Raw(@Html.Raw(Model.Glyphicon)</span>`